# How to apply white balance coefficents to RAW image for sRGB output

Tags: image, image-processing, rust, rgb, raw

I want to convert RAW image data (RGGB) to sRGB image. There are many specialized ways to do this but to first understand the basics, I've implemented some easy alogrithms like debayering by resolution-reduction.
My current pipeline is:

- Rescale the u16 input data by *blacklevel* and *whitelevel*
- Apply white balance coefficents
- Debayer with size reduction, average for G: g=((g0+g1)/2)
- Calculate pseudo-inverse for D65 illuminant XYZ_TO_CAM (from Adobe DNG)
- Convert debayered RGB data to XYZ by CAM_TO_XYZ
- Convert XYZ to D65 sRGB (matrix taken from Bruce Lindbloom)
- Apply gamma correction (simple routine for now, should be replaced by sRGB gamma)
- Rescale from [minval..maxval] to [0..1] and convert f32 to u16
- Save as tiff

The problem is that if I skip the white balance coefficent multiplication (or just replace them by 1.0) the output image already looks acceptable. If I apply the coefficents (taken from AsShot in DNG) the output has a huge color cast. And I'm not sure if I have to multiply by *coef* or *1/coef*.

The first image is the result of the pipeline with wb_coefs set to 1.0.

[image]

The second image is the result with the "correct" wb_coefs.

[image]

What is wrong in my pipeline?

Additional question:

- I'm not sure about the rescaling process. Do I've to rescale into [0..1] after every step or is it enough to rescale during u16 conversion as final stage?

Full code:

```rust
macro_rules! max {
  ($x: expr) => ($x);
  ($x: expr, $($z: expr),+) => {{
      let y = max!($($z),*);
      if $x > y {
          $x
      } else {
          y
      }
  }}
}

macro_rules! min {
  ($x: expr) => ($x);
  ($x: expr, $($z: expr),+) => {{
      let y = min!($($z),*);
      if $x < y {
          $x
      } else {
          y
      }
  }}
}

/// sRGB D65
const XYZD65_TO_SRGB: [[f32; 3]; 4] = [
  [3.2404542, -1.5371385, -0.4985314],
  [-0.9692660, 1.8760108, 0.0415560],
  [0.0556434, -0.2040259, 1.0572252],
  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
];

// buf: RAW image data
fn to_srgb(buf: &Vec<u16>, width: usize, height: usize) {
  let w = width / 2;
  let h = height / 2;

  let blacklevel: [u16; 4] = [511, 511, 511, 511];
  let whitelevel: [u16; 4] = [12735, 12735, 12735, 12735];

  let xyz2cam_d65: [[i32; 3]; 4] = [[6722, -635, -963], [-4287, 12460, 2028], [-908, 2162, 5668], [0, 0, 0]];
  let cam2xyz = convert_matrix::<4>(xyz2cam_d65);
  eprintln!("CAM_TO_XYZ: {:?}", cam2xyz);

  // from DNG
  // As Shot Neutral: 0.518481 1 0.545842
  //let wb_coef = [1.0/0.518481, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0/0.545842];
  //let wb_coef = [0.518481, 1.0, 1.0, 0.545842];
  let wb_coef = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0];

  // b/w level correction, rescale, debayer
  let mut rgb = vec![0.0_f32; width / 2 * height / 2 * 3];
  for row in 0..h {
    for col in 0..w {
      let r0 = buf[(row * 2 + 0) * width + (col * 2) + 0];
      let g0 = buf[(row * 2 + 0) * width + (col * 2) + 1];
      let g1 = buf[(row * 2 + 1) * width + (col * 2) + 0];
      let b0 = buf[(row * 2 + 1) * width + (col * 2) + 1];
      let r0 = ((r0.saturating_sub(blacklevel[0])) as f32 / (whitelevel[0] - blacklevel[0]) as f32) * wb_coef[0];
      let g0 = ((g0.saturating_sub(blacklevel[1])) as f32 / (whitelevel[1] - blacklevel[1]) as f32) * wb_coef[1];
      let g1 = ((g1.saturating_sub(blacklevel[2])) as f32 / (whitelevel[2] - blacklevel[2]) as f32) * wb_coef[2];
      let b0 = ((b0.saturating_sub(blacklevel[3])) as f32 / (whitelevel[3] - blacklevel[3]) as f32) * wb_coef[3];
      rgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 0] = r0;
      rgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 1] = (g0 + g1) / 2.0;
      rgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 2] = b0;
    }
  }

  // Convert to XYZ by CAM_TO_XYZ from D65 illuminant
  let mut xyz = vec![0.0_f32; w * h * 3];
  for row in 0..h {
    for col in 0..w {
      let r = rgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 0];
      let g = rgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 1];
      let b = rgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 2];
      xyz[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 0] = cam2xyz[0][0] * r + cam2xyz[0][1] * g + cam2xyz[0][2] * b;
      xyz[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 1] = cam2xyz[1][0] * r + cam2xyz[1][1] * g + cam2xyz[1][2] * b;
      xyz[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 2] = cam2xyz[2][0] * r + cam2xyz[2][1] * g + cam2xyz[2][2] * b;
    }
  }

  // Track min/max value for rescaling/clipping
  let mut maxval = 1.0;
  let mut minval = 0.0;

  // Convert to sRGB from XYZ
  let mut srgb = vec![0.0; w * h * 3];
  for row in 0..h {
    for col in 0..w {
      let r = xyz[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 0] as f32;
      let g = xyz[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 1] as f32;
      let b = xyz[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 2] as f32;
      srgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 0] = XYZD65_TO_SRGB[0][0] * r + XYZD65_TO_SRGB[0][1] * g + XYZD65_TO_SRGB[0][2] * b;
      srgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 1] = XYZD65_TO_SRGB[1][0] * r + XYZD65_TO_SRGB[1][1] * g + XYZD65_TO_SRGB[1][2] * b;
      srgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 2] = XYZD65_TO_SRGB[2][0] * r + XYZD65_TO_SRGB[2][1] * g + XYZD65_TO_SRGB[2][2] * b;
      let r = srgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 0];
      let g = srgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 1];
      let b = srgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 2];
      maxval = max!(maxval, r, g, b);
      minval = min!(minval, r, g, b);
    }
  }

  gamma_corr(&mut srgb, w, h, 2.2);

  let mut output = vec![0_u16; w * h * 3];
  for row in 0..h {
    for col in 0..w {
      let r = srgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 0];
      let g = srgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 1];
      let b = srgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 2];
      output[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 0] = (clip(r, minval, maxval) * (u16::MAX as f32)) as u16;
      output[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 1] = (clip(g, minval, maxval) * (u16::MAX as f32)) as u16;
      output[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 2] = (clip(b, minval, maxval) * (u16::MAX as f32)) as u16;
    }
  }

  let img = DynamicImage::ImageRgb16(ImageBuffer::from_raw(w as u32, h as u32, output).unwrap());
  img.save_with_format("/tmp/test.tif", image::ImageFormat::Tiff).unwrap();
}

fn pseudoinverse<const N: usize>(matrix: [[f32; 3]; N]) -> [[f32; 3]; N] {
  let mut result: [[f32; 3]; N] = [Default::default(); N];

  let mut work: [[f32; 6]; 3] = [Default::default(); 3];
  let mut num: f32 = 0.0;
  for i in 0..3 {
    for j in 0..6 {
      work[i][j] = if j == i + 3 { 1.0 } else { 0.0 };
    }
    for j in 0..3 {
      for k in 0..N {
        work[i][j] += matrix[k][i] * matrix[k][j];
      }
    }
  }
  for i in 0..3 {
    num = work[i][i];
    for j in 0..6 {
      work[i][j] /= num;
    }
    for k in 0..3 {
      if k == i {
        continue;
      }
      num = work[k][i];
      for j in 0..6 {
        work[k][j] -= work[i][j] * num;
      }
    }
  }
  for i in 0..N {
    for j in 0..3 {
      result[i][j] = 0.0;
      for k in 0..3 {
        result[i][j] += work[j][k + 3] * matrix[i][k];
      }
    }
  }

  result
}

fn convert_matrix<const N: usize>(adobe_xyz_to_cam: [[i32; 3]; N]) -> [[f32; N]; 3] {
  let mut xyz_to_cam: [[f32; 3]; N] = [[0.0; 3]; N];
  let mut cam_to_xyz: [[f32; N]; 3] = [[0.0; N]; 3];

  for i in 0..N {
    for j in 0..3 {
      xyz_to_cam[i][j] = adobe_xyz_to_cam[i][j] as f32 / 10000.0;
    }
  }
  eprintln!("XYZ_TO_CAM: {:?}", xyz_to_cam);
  let inverse = pseudoinverse::<N>(xyz_to_cam);
  for i in 0..3 {
    for j in 0..N {
      cam_to_xyz[i][j] = inverse[j][i];
    }
  }
  cam_to_xyz
}

fn clip(v: f32, minval: f32, maxval: f32) -> f32 {
  (v + minval.abs()) / (maxval + minval.abs())
}

// https://kosinix.github.io/raster/docs/src/raster/filter.rs.html#339-359
fn gamma_corr(rgb: &mut Vec<f32>, w: usize, h: usize, gamma: f32) {
  for row in 0..h {
    for col in 0..w {
      let r = rgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 0];
      let g = rgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 1];
      let b = rgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 2];
      rgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 0] = r.powf(1.0 / gamma);
      rgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 1] = g.powf(1.0 / gamma);
      rgb[row * w * 3 + (col * 3) + 2] = b.powf(1.0 / gamma);
    }
  }
}
```

The DNG for this example can be found at: https://chaospixel.com/pub/misc/dng/sample.dng (~40 MiB).

Comment: According to the following [guide](https://rcsumner.net/raw_guide/RAWguide.pdf), you have tp use `1/AsShotNeutral` (but the guide is not accurate). You may follow [Developing A RAW Photo By Hand](https://www.odelama.com/photo/Developing-a-RAW-Photo-by-hand/) part 1 and 2. Note: the site looks broken - for viewing the images I have to zoom in and out in my browser. I could have helped you better, if the implementation were in Python or MATLAB.

Comment: I tried to follow your code. I think the problem is in the stage "Rescale from [minval..maxval] to [0..1]". You don't have to track min/max value: `maxval = max!(maxval, r, g, b);`. Instead of `clip(r, minval, maxval)`, use `clip(r, 0.0, 1.0)` (same for `g` and `b`).

Comment: @Rotem The tracking was because I've read that just clipping 0..1 could lead to magenta cast in the highlights, so you have to track the maximum and reduce all channels by the same amount instead just clipping one or two overflowing channels. Not sure if my approach is correct. In your linked article, there is a good hint: as the WB is ~1.9, 1.0, ~1.8, these must be scaled so none is >1.0. I've added this and also added just clip(..., 0.0, 1.0) but the result still have an extreme color cast. Now it's red/magenta instead of green, because with 1,9, 1,0, 1,8 the green part is much lower.

Comment: I guess problem is in the stage "Calculate pseudo-inverse for D65 illuminant XYZ_TO_CAM". According to [odelama](https://www.odelama.com/photo/Developing-a-RAW-Photo-by-hand/Developing-a-RAW-Photo-by-hand_Part-2/), you suppose to use `ForwardMatrix1` and `ForwardMatrix2` (try using only `ForwardMatrix2`). Convert it from XYZD50 to XYZD65 first.

Comment: @Rotem I don't have a ForwardMatrix and the DNG spec says if the ForwardMatrix is missing, you have to use the pseudo inverse of the XYZ_TO_CAM matrix.

Comment: The issue is that inv(XYZ_TO_CAM) includes most of the white balance correction coefficients. In case you still want to use it, you have to compute: `rgb2cam = xyz2cam * rgb2xyz` and Normalize rows to 1: `rgb2cam = rgb2cam ./ repmat(sum(rgb2cam,2),1,3);` (Check [here](https://rcsumner.net/raw_guide/RAWguide.pdf)).

Comment: You may have `ForwardMatrix`, but you need exif tool for extracting it.

Comment: @Rotem I've written the dng converter by myself (https://github.com/dnglab/dnglab) and re-use the generic conversion matrix from https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/blob/master/src/external/adobe_coeff.c. As Darktable and RawTherapee are capable of decoding my DNGs without the ForwardMatrix, I'm sure it must mork (by one or another way...)

Comment: @Rotem How coud inv(XYZ_TO_CAM) includes any white balance correction? the matrix is constant for every raw (it is specific to the camera model). So if I take the the same scene with custom WB K 3000° and 7000° there can't be any WB correction encoded in the matrix.

Comment: Large part of the correction is a result of the optics characteristics. The optics has good transfer of the green and blocks a lot of the blue and red

Comment: “Rescale from [minval..maxval] to [0..1]” means you undo any effects of whitebalancing and blacklevel correction. It basically makes most of your earlier computation steps irrelevant. If you do want to scale to avoid clipping, scale all channels equally, and leave 0 where it is (clip the negative values to 0).

Comment: Placing 200 reputation bounty implies that finding a solution is important for you. In case it's important for you, please try yo share the DNG image. Sharing the DNG image allows one to compare the solution to RawTherapee result, and prove it is correct.

Comment: @Rotem I've added the link, it's: https://chaospixel.com/pub/misc/dng/sample.dng

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main reason for getting wrong colors is that we have to normalize the rows of `rgb2cam` matrix to `1`, as described in the following [guide](https://rcsumner.net/raw_guide/RAWguide.pdf).

According to [DNG spec](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/dng_spec_1.4.0.0.pdf):

> ColorMatrix1 defines a transformation matrix that converts XYZ values to reference camera native color space values, under the first calibration illuminant.

It means that if the calibration illuminant is D65, the ColorMatrix converts XYZ to "camera RGB".
(Convert it as is, without using any white balance scaling coefficients).

- The inverse ColorMatrix, converts from "camera RGB" to XYZ.
  After converting XYZ to sRGB, the result is **color balanced** sRGB.
  The conclusions is that ColorMatrix includes the while balance coefficients in it (the white balancing coefficients apply D65 illuminant).
- Normalizing the rows of `rgb2cam` to `1` neutralizes the while balance coefficients, and keeps only the "Color Correction Matrix" (the math is a bit complicated).
- Without normalizing the rows, we are scaling by while balance multipliers two times:

1. Scale coefficients from ColorMatrix that balances the input to D65.
2. Scale coefficients taken from AsShotNatural that balances the input to the illuminant of the scene (illuminant of the scene is close to D65).
   The result of scaling twice is an extreme color cast.

---

Tracking the maximum in order to avoid "magenta cast in the highlights":

Instead of tracking the actual maximum color values in the input image, we suppose to track the "theoretical maximum color value".

- Take `whitelevel - blacklevel` and scale by the white balance multipliers.
  Track the result...

The guiding rule is that the colors supposed to be the same in both cases:

- Applying the processing to small patches of the image, and places the patches together (where we can't track the global minimum and maximum).
- Applying the processing to the entire image.

I suppose you have to track the maximum of scaled `whitelevel - blacklevel`, only when white balance multipliers are less than `1`.
When all the multipliers are `1` or above, we can clip the result to `1.0`, without tracking the maximum.
Note:

- there is probably an advantage of scaling down, and tracking the maximum, but I don't know this subject.
  In my solution we just multiply upper (above 1.0), and clip the result.

---

The solution is based on [Processing RAW Images in MATLAB](https://rcsumner.net/raw_guide/RAWguide.pdf) guide.

I am posting both MATLAB implementation and Python implementation (but no Rust implementation).

---

The first step is extracting the raw Bayer image from `sample.dng` using [dcraw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dcraw) command line:

```
dcraw -4 -D -T sample.dng
```

Rename the tiff output to `sample__lin_bayer.tif`.

---

Conversion process:

- Rescale the `uint16` input data by `blacklevel` and `whitelevel` (subtract `blacklevel` from all the pixels and scale by `whitelevel - blacklevel`).
- Apply white balance scaling coefficients.
  The scaling coefficients equals `1./AsShotNatural`.
  Scale the red pixels in the Bayer alignment by the red scaling coefficient, scale the greens by the green scaling, and the blues by the blue scaling.
  Assumption: the minimum scaling is `1.0` and the others are above `1.0` (we my divide by the minimum scaling to make sure).
- Clip the scaled result to [0, 1] (clipping is required due to `demosaic` implementation limitations).
- Demosaicing (Debayer) using MATLAB `demosaic` function or `cv2.cvtColor` in Python.
- Calculate `rgb2cam` matrix: `rgb2cam = ColorMatrix * rgb2xyz`.
  `rgb2xyz` matrix is taken from [Bruce Lindbloom site](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html).
- Normalize rows of `rgb2cam` matrix so the sum of each row equals `1` (divide each row by the sum of the row).
- Compute `cam2rgb` matrix by inverting `rgb2cam`: `cam2rgb = inv(rgb2cam)`.
  `cam2rgb` is the "CCM matrix" (Color Correction Matrix).
- Left multiply matrix `cam2rgb` by each RGB tuple (apply color correction).
- Apply gamma correction (use sRGB standard gamma).
- Convert to `uint8` and save as PNG (PNG format is used for posting in SO website).

---

MATLAB Implementation:

```matlab
filename = 'sample__lin_bayer.tif'; % Output of: dcraw -4 -D -T sample.dng

% Exif information:
blacklevel = 511; % blacklevel = meta_info.SubIFDs{1}.BlackLevel(1);
whitelevel = 12735; % whitelevel = meta_info.SubIFDs{1}.WhiteLevel;
AsShotNeutral = [0.5185 1 0.5458];
ColorMatrix = [ 0.6722   -0.0635   -0.0963
               -0.4287    1.2460    0.2028
               -0.0908    0.2162    0.5668];
bayer_type = 'rggb';


% Constant matrix for converting sRGB to XYZ(D65):
% http://www.brucelindbloom.com/Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html
rgb2xyz = [0.4124564  0.3575761  0.1804375
           0.2126729  0.7151522  0.0721750
           0.0193339  0.1191920  0.9503041];


% Read input image (Bayer mosaic alignment, pixels data type is uint16):
raw = imread(filename);

% "Linearizing":
% There is no LinearizationTable so we only have to subtract the black level.
% Convert from range [blacklevel, whitelevel] to range [0, 1].
lin_bayer = (double(raw) - blacklevel) / (whitelevel - blacklevel);
lin_bayer = max(0, min(lin_bayer, 1));

% The White Balance multipliers are 1./AsShotNeutral
wb_multipliers = 1./AsShotNeutral;
r_scale = wb_multipliers(1); % Assume value is above 1
g_scale = wb_multipliers(2); % Assume value = 1
b_scale = wb_multipliers(3); % Assume value is above 1

% Bayer alignment is RGGB:
% R G
% G B
%
% Apply white balancing to linear Bayer image.
balanced_bayer = lin_bayer;
balanced_bayer(1:2:end, 1:2:end) = balanced_bayer(1:2:end, 1:2:end)*r_scale; % Red   (indices [1, 3, 5,... ; 1, 3, 5,... ])
balanced_bayer(1:2:end, 2:2:end) = balanced_bayer(1:2:end, 2:2:end)*g_scale; % Green (indices [1, 3, 5,... ; 2, 4, 6,... ])
balanced_bayer(2:2:end, 1:2:end) = balanced_bayer(2:2:end, 1:2:end)*g_scale; % Green (indices [2, 4, 6,... ; 1, 3, 5,... ])
balanced_bayer(2:2:end, 2:2:end) = balanced_bayer(2:2:end, 2:2:end)*b_scale; % Blue  (indices [2, 4, 6,... ; 2, 4, 6,... ])

% Clip to range [0, 1] for avoiding "pinkish highlights" (avoiding "magenta cast" in the highlights).
balanced_bayer = min(balanced_bayer, 1);

% Demosaicing
temp = uint16(balanced_bayer*(2^16-1)); % Convert from double to uint16, because MATLAB demosaic() function requires a uint8 or uint16 input.
lin_rgb = double(demosaic(temp, bayer_type))/(2^16-1); % Apply Demosaicing and convert range back type double and range [0, 1].

% Color Space Conversion
xyz2cam = ColorMatrix; % ColorMatrix applies XYZ(D65) to CAM_rgb
rgb2cam = xyz2cam * rgb2xyz;

% Result:
% rgb2cam = [0.2619    0.1835    0.0252
%            0.0921    0.7620    0.2053
%            0.0195    0.1897    0.5379]

% Normalize rows to 1. MATLAB shortcut: rgb2cam = rgb2cam ./ repmat(sum(rgb2cam,2),1,3);

rows_sum = sum(rgb2cam, 2);
% Result:
% rows_sum = [0.4706
%             1.0593
%             0.7470]

% Divide element of every row by the sum of the row:
rgb2cam(1, :) = rgb2cam(1, :) / rows_sum(1); % Divide top row
rgb2cam(2, :) = rgb2cam(2, :) / rows_sum(2); % Divide center row
rgb2cam(3, :) = rgb2cam(3, :) / rows_sum(3); % Divide bottom row
% Result (sum of every row is 1):
% rgb2cam = [0.5566    0.3899    0.0535
%            0.0869    0.7193    0.1938
%            0.0261    0.2539    0.7200]

cam2rgb = inv(rgb2cam); % Invert matrix
% Result:
% cam2rgb = [ 1.9644   -1.1197    0.1553
%            -0.2412    1.6738   -0.4326
%             0.0139   -0.5498    1.5359]

R = lin_rgb(:, :, 1);
G = lin_rgb(:, :, 2);
B = lin_rgb(:, :, 3);

% Left multiply matrix cam2rgb by each RGB tuple (convert from "camera RGB" to "linear sRGB").
sR = cam2rgb(1,1)*R + cam2rgb(1,2)*G + cam2rgb(1,3)*B;
sG = cam2rgb(2,1)*R + cam2rgb(2,2)*G + cam2rgb(2,3)*B;
sB = cam2rgb(3,1)*R + cam2rgb(3,2)*G + cam2rgb(3,3)*B;

lin_srgb = cat(3, sR, sG, sB);
lin_srgb = max(min(lin_srgb, 1), 0); % Clip to range [0, 1]

% Convet from "Linear sRGB" to sRGB (apply gamma)
sRGB = lin2rgb(lin_srgb); % lin2rgb MATLAB functions uses the exact formula [you may approximate it to power of (1/gamma)].

% Show the result, and save to sRGB.png
figure;imshow(sRGB);impixelinfo;title('sRGB'); 
imwrite(im2uint8(sRGB), 'sRGB.png');



% Inverting 3x3 matrix (some help of MATLAB Symbolic Toolbox):
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Assume:
% A = [ a11, a12, a13]
%     [ a21, a22, a23]
%     [ a31, a32, a33]
%
% 1. Compute determinant of A:
% detA = a11*a22*a33 - a11*a23*a32 - a12*a21*a33 + a12*a23*a31 + a13*a21*a32 - a13*a22*a31
%
% 2. Compute the inverse of the matrix A:
% invA = [  (a22*a33 - a23*a32)/detA, -(a12*a33 - a13*a32)/detA,  (a12*a23 - a13*a22)/detA
%          -(a21*a33 - a23*a31)/detA,  (a11*a33 - a13*a31)/detA, -(a11*a23 - a13*a21)/detA
%           (a21*a32 - a22*a31)/detA, -(a11*a32 - a12*a31)/detA,  (a11*a22 - a12*a21)/detA]
```

---

Python implementation:

```python
import numpy as np
import cv2


def lin2rgb(im):
    """ Convert im from "Linear sRGB" to sRGB - apply Gamma. """
    # sRGB standard applies gamma = 2.4, Break Point = 0.00304 (and computed Slope = 12.92)    
    g = 2.4
    bp = 0.00304
    inv_g = 1/g
    sls = 1 / (g/(bp**(inv_g - 1)) - g*bp + bp)
    fs = g*sls / (bp**(inv_g - 1))
    co = fs*bp**(inv_g) - sls*bp

    srgb = im.copy()
    srgb[im <= bp] = sls * im[im <= bp]
    srgb[im > bp] = np.power(fs*im[im > bp], inv_g) - co
    return srgb


filename = 'sample__lin_bayer.tif'  # Output of: dcraw -4 -D -T sample.dng

# Exif information:
blacklevel = 511
whitelevel = 12735
AsShotNeutral = np.array([0.5185, 1, 0.5458])
ColorMatrix = np.array([[ 0.6722, -0.0635, -0.0963],
                        [-0.4287,  1.2460,  0.2028],
                        [-0.0908,  0.2162,  0.5668]])
# bayer_type = 'rggb'


# Constant matrix for converting sRGB to XYZ(D65):
# http://www.brucelindbloom.com/Eqn_RGB_XYZ_Matrix.html
rgb2xyz = np.array([[0.4124564, 0.3575761, 0.1804375],
                    [0.2126729, 0.7151522, 0.0721750],
                    [0.0193339, 0.1191920, 0.9503041]])


# Read input image (Bayer mosaic alignement, pixeles data type is np.uint16):
raw = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# "Linearizing":
# There is no LinearizationTable so we only have to subtract the black level.
# Convert from range [blacklevel, whitelevel] to range [0, 1] (convert type to np.float64).
lin_bayer = (raw.astype(np.float64) - blacklevel) / (whitelevel - blacklevel)
lin_bayer = lin_bayer.clip(0, 1)

# The White Balance multipliers are 1./AsShotNeutral
wb_multipliers = 1 / AsShotNeutral
r_scale = wb_multipliers[0]  # Assume value is above 1
g_scale = wb_multipliers[1]  # Assume value = 1
b_scale = wb_multipliers[2]  # Assume value is above 1

# Bayer alignment is RGGB:
# R G
# G B
#
# Apply white balancing to linear Bayer image.
balanced_bayer = lin_bayer.copy()
balanced_bayer[0::2, 0::2] = balanced_bayer[0::2, 0::2]*r_scale  # Red   (indices [0, 2, 4,... ; 0, 2, 4,... ])
balanced_bayer[0::2, 1::2] = balanced_bayer[0::2, 1::2]*g_scale  # Green (indices [0, 2, 4,... ; 1, 3, 5,... ])
balanced_bayer[1::2, 0::2] = balanced_bayer[1::2, 0::2]*g_scale  # Green (indices [1, 3, 5,... ; 0, 2, 4,... ])
balanced_bayer[1::2, 1::2] = balanced_bayer[1::2, 1::2]*b_scale  # Blue  (indices [1, 3, 5,... ; 0, 2, 4,... ])

# Clip to range [0, 1] for avoiding "pinkish highlights" (avoiding "magenta cast" in the highlights).
balanced_bayer = np.minimum(balanced_bayer, 1)

# Demosaicing:
temp = np.round((balanced_bayer*(2**16-1))).astype(np.uint16)  # Convert from double to np.uint16, because OpenCV demosaic() function requires a uint8 or uint16 input.
lin_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(temp, cv2.COLOR_BayerBG2RGB).astype(np.float64)/(2**16-1)  # Apply Demosaicing and convert back to np.float64 in range [0, 1] (is there a bug in OpenCV Bayer naming?).

# Color Space Conversion
xyz2cam = ColorMatrix  # ColorMatrix applies XYZ(D65) to CAM_rgb
rgb2cam = xyz2cam @ rgb2xyz

# Result:
# rgb2cam = [0.2619    0.1835    0.0252
#            0.0921    0.7620    0.2053
#            0.0195    0.1897    0.5379]

# Normalize rows to 1. MATLAB shortcut: rgb2cam = rgb2cam ./ repmat(sum(rgb2cam,2),1,3);

rows_sum = np.sum(rgb2cam, 1)
# Result:
# rows_sum = [0.4706
#             1.0593
#             0.7470]

# Divide element of every row by the sum of the row:
rgb2cam[0, :] = rgb2cam[0, :] / rows_sum[0]  # Divide top row
rgb2cam[1, :] = rgb2cam[1, :] / rows_sum[1]  # Divide center row
rgb2cam[2, :] = rgb2cam[2, :] / rows_sum[2]  # Divide bottom row
# Result (sum of every row is 1):
# rgb2cam = [0.5566    0.3899    0.0535
#            0.0869    0.7193    0.1938
#            0.0261    0.2539    0.7200]

cam2rgb = np.linalg.inv(rgb2cam)  # Invert matrix
# Result:
# cam2rgb = [ 1.9644   -1.1197    0.1553
#            -0.2412    1.6738   -0.4326
#             0.0139   -0.5498    1.5359]

r = lin_rgb[:, :, 0]
g = lin_rgb[:, :, 1]
b = lin_rgb[:, :, 2]

# Left multiply matrix cam2rgb by each RGB tuple (convert from "camera RGB" to "linear sRGB").
sr = cam2rgb[0, 0]*r + cam2rgb[0, 1]*g + cam2rgb[0, 2]*b
sg = cam2rgb[1, 0]*r + cam2rgb[1, 1]*g + cam2rgb[1, 2]*b
sb = cam2rgb[2, 0]*r + cam2rgb[2, 1]*g + cam2rgb[2, 2]*b

lin_srgb = np.dstack([sr, sg, sb])
lin_srgb = lin_srgb.clip(0, 1)  # Clip to range [0, 1]

# Convert from "Linear sRGB" to sRGB (apply gamma)
sRGB = lin2rgb(lin_srgb)  # lin2rgb MATLAB functions uses the exact formula [you may approximate it to power of (1/gamma)].

# Save to sRGB.png
cv2.imwrite('sRGB.png', cv2.cvtColor((sRGB*255).astype(np.uint8), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
```

---

Results (downscaled):

Result of [RawTherapee](https://www.rawtherapee.com/) (all enhancements are disabled):
[image]

MATLAB result:
[image]

Python result:
[image]

---

Note:

- The result looks dark due to low exposure (and because we didn't apply any brightness correction).

Comment: Excellent answer, now I understand the difference between the WB from the matrix and WB from AsShot. I was able to fix my code and the output is now correct. One thing isn't still clear to me: Is the D65 WB correction embedded into the XYZ2CAM matrix from DNG or the SRGB2XYZ (which is relative to D65)? As the rescale to 1 is applied after the multiplication of both matrices. Would it be enough to rescale only one of these matrices?

Comment: `sRGB2XYZ` is a constant linear transformation matrix that used for converting from sRGB color space to XYZ color space (it has no WB information). `XYZ2CAM` indirectly embeds the D65 WB coefficients. For getting the WB coefficients from `XYZ2CAM`, we need to apply color space converting (because the WB applies "Camera RGB" color space). I think (but **not sure**) that AsShotNeutral of D65 equals `rows_sum / max(row_sum)` = `[0.4442 , 1.0, 0.7052]` - the values are specific to your camera.